# Installing Fastclick within famo.us

Tags: famo.us

According to most Famo.us tutorials, you only need to add the following line to make Fastclick work (Famo.us university Timbre project)

```
var FastClick        = require('famous/inputs/FastClick');
```

However, I have found that that alone doesn't kill the 300ms delay in an iPhone 5. Is there any additional configuration to be done? I included the FastClick line for the following code:

```
this.accordionSurface.on('click', function() {
  this._eventOutput.emit('editItem', this.model);
}.bind(this));
```

This is part of a `AccordionView` that is then added to a `Scrollview` through a `ViewSequence` (copied from the Taasky demo at https://launch-demos.famo.us/Taasky/). However, unlike the demo, tapping on my items takes some time to react. The animation done after tapping on my item looks like this:

```
AccordionView.prototype.hide = function(scrollView) {
this.accordionModifier.setOpacity(
  0,{ duration : 100, curve: 'easeInOut' },function(){
    this.size.set(0.001, {duration: 300, curve: 'easeOut'}, function(){
    }.bind(this));
  }.bind(this));
}
```

The animation works fine and smooth, but it's triggered with a bit of delay that I assume comes from the lack of the FastClick integration. I had moved the `require` line around the `AppView`, `main.js` without result and I have yet to find an example that does anything else that calling FastClick with the `require` line.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly a fix but we've noticed that the 'touchend' event (or 'end' event in a GenericSync) fires reliably and could be used as an alternative to click with a bit of tinkering.